# How to use Command-c/Command-v shortcut in Mac to copy/paste text?

Tags: java, swing, copy, paste, macos

I have a Java Swing application that i want to run on Mac OS X. I want to use the normal Mac copy/paste shortcuts to copy/paste text to a text field in my Java application.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does the trick but i want to use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> & <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> instead. How can i do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using a 3rd-party L&F implementation it probably doesn't support the Mac's native keyboard shortcuts. The following code should reinstate the Mac's keyboard shortcuts for `JTextField`s after setting the L&F:

```
InputMap im = (InputMap) UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
```

Of course you'll only need to do this if you detect that the application is running on a Mac so that you don't affect the keyboard mappings for other OS's.

Comment: +1, (since I don't use a MAC) I keep forgetting the `META_DOWN_MASK` is the command key on MAC.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the value, use [`getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMask%28%29).

Comment: I run this code inside this: if (System.getProperty("os.name", "").toUpperCase().startsWith("MAC"))

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen, know of or are using the SWT (Standard Widget Toolkit) maintained by Eclipse? That has a key press (SWT.COMMAND) for command.

Comment: I am using Swing. Is there a way to do this in Swing ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running pure Swing?  If so it should do that automatically(note it may not make the little menu animation if you dont use an Application bundle).  If not then you will have to consult the documentation for whatever API you are using.

Just tested it and it works fine on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I have a Mac book and only Ctrl+v works to paste text in a JTextField ... Command+v does not work.

Comment: What version of the OS are you using?  Also, what look and feel are you using?  If its the default then the bindings should work(and if they do not you may need to file a bug report with Apple).  I tested a really basic Swing app just now and cmd-c/v work just fine, but I used the default look and feel on Snow Leopard.