# How can I detect if the button specified as the menu shortcut mask is down during a mouse event?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I'm handling a Swing mouse event, and I'd like to know if the key mask specified in `Toolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask()` is down when the event occurs. I obviously cannot use the usual `MouseEvent.isControlDown()` method, since that will not work properly on Mac OSes since I want to use the Command key on the Mac.

I also don't want it to trigger if any other modifier keys are down. I *only* want it to return true when Ctrl/Command is the only key down. I assume I'll need to use `MouseEvent.getModifiersEx()`, but I'm not positive how to construct the comparison.

Comment: Would META_DOWN_MASK do the trick? Found it on this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252749/java-how-to-use-command-c-command-v-shortcut-in-mac-to-copy-paste-text

Comment: @UweeNukr That would still leave me in the same place. I have the mask value, I just don't know how to check to see if it's pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by using `getModifiers()` instead of `getModifiersEx()`:

```
public static boolean isMenuShortcutKeyDown(MouseEvent me) {
    return me.getModifiers() == Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
}
```

If there's any flaw with using `getModifiers()`, please point it out, but this seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because the modifiers are provided a bit-mask and other modifiers might be active at the same time, you should not use ==, but rather:

```
public static boolean isMenuShortcutKeyDown(MouseEvent me) {
    return (me.getModifiers() & Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()) != 0;
}
```