# Java : Mac command key for multiple selection in a list (instead of control)

Tags: java, macos, command, controls, selection

I would like use the "command" key instead of "control" key when i'm running my program on mac.

I have got a list with a click listener; today on mac, to select multiple items I use "control" + click. I would like use "command" + click.

Is there any way to change the key or change the keyboard with java ?

Then with :

```
if (os.startsWith("Mac OS X"){}
```

I could use the key only on mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to use Command-c/Command-v shortcut in Mac to copy/paste text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252749/how-to-use-command-c-command-v-shortcut-in-mac-to-copy-paste-text) - Use this for using the command key.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/ - Use this for getting the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

use `System.getProperties(os.name)` to get the name of your Operating System

Answer (score 0):

- You can detect the current os.

  ```
  public class MachineUtil {

          private static final String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(new Locale(""));

          /**
          * Returns true if the operating system is a form of Linux.
          */
          public static boolean isLinux() {
          return os.indexOf("linux") >= 0;
          }

          /**
          * Returns true if the operating system is a form of Windows.
          */
          public static boolean isWindows() {
          return os.indexOf("win") >= 0;
          }

          /**
          * Returns true if the operating system is a form of Mac OS.
          */
          public static boolean isMac() {
          return os.indexOf("mac") >= 0;
          }}
  ```