# How to change font for JMeter? (upper i same as lower L now)

Tags: java, swing, jmeter

I've done web search and found only links on how to change **size** of the font:
[How to change font size for JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899553/how-to-change-font-size-for-jmeter/)

I'm on `MacOS` `JMeter 5.1` and font inside controls shows upper `i` same as lower `L`. As I've started to read answer to size issue, I came to know what `HiDPI` and `swing` for java cross-platform is.

Uncommenting `jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=24` in `jmeter.properties` have not resulted in any visible effect, using `Zoom` does change size of font, but i-L issue persists at larger scales.

What are my options?

1. download source of JMeter, rebuild. - complex for me, at first glance least desirable. Where font name is set in source?
2. try to use `swing` functionality. Not sure it is doable w/out rebuild of JMeter. As for swing I've only read [What font in Swing looks the same in all OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187989/what-font-in-swing-looks-the-same-in-all-os) now and answer to font size:

> Now for fonts, you can use Swing mechanism. To do that, add to
>   jmeter.sh or jmeter.bat the JVM System property:
>
> -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Dialog-20
>
> And ensure you use the Cross Platform LAF .

But "interestingly" with `Cross Platform LAF` copy-paste does not work on my Mac. Command-C works on some LAF, but does not on others (including Cross Platform). "upper i same as lower L" issue is visible on all LAFs.

3. Try MacOS font substitution. Not sure again if it is doable. quick web search for `macos font substitution` did not find that specifically, some default font changes etc. What font JMeter uses?

ADDED:
Below is what happened after script run from the asnwer, some parts became not fit to space, some too small.

[image: Screen after script run]

Comment: On Mac for swing LAFs text copy-paste works with Ctrl-C/V, not Command-C/V, so it is workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If copy paste shortcuts don't work on Mac you should raise this issue via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)
2. You can change JMeter font to whatever you like by adding the next lines to [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   swing.aatext=true
   swing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Comic Sans MS
   swing.plaf.metal.userFont=Comic Sans MS
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up
3. As the last resort you can always go for [Groovy scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and change the font directly in the runtime like:

   ```
   import javax.swing.*
   import java.awt.Font

   def keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys()
   keys.each { key ->
       def value = UIManager.get(key)
       if (value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource) {
           UIManager.put(key, new javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 24))
       }
   }
   ```

   as the result you will get the best JMeter UX ever:

   [image]

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for you trying to help. However, swing works only for metal (`swing.plaf.metal`), right? I've tried to add same properties for `darcula` and saw no  difference in interface. Is it that some looks are made on swing and other on ...?
The script changes something, but I added screen to my question and it does not look good, besides, I want to change font where I type, e.g. `Name`, `Comment` of element and font still had non-distinguishable `I` in them.

Comment: For some reason in Metal look copy-paste of text does not work on Macbook. Is it some `swing` issue or maybe Jmeter specific? I can report to bugzilla of cause.

Comment: I don't have a Mac hence I cannot tell for sure what LAF is being used there, you can switch JMeter's LAF to `Metal` or `CrossPlatform` via "Options -> Look and Feel" menu and the above hint should work. You can report to bugzilla of course, but my expectation is that they will suggest to ask your boyfriend for help as this is not related to JMeter/Swing. 2nd approach should work for all LAFs.

Comment: Not related? On MacOS, Darcula LAFs copy-paste works, on Metal and cross does not. Why not related?

Comment: Looking into JMeter source code either `Control+C` or `Command+C` should work depending on the context

Comment: Where do you look? Can code be changed to provide for answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252749/how-to-use-command-c-command-v-shortcut-in-mac-to-copy-paste-text (just found it)?